# count specific integer value in a row across specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have pandas dataframe with 12 columns each having value 0 to 12 randomly. I want to create new columns which will contain the count of these specific value. for example newvar1 will contain count of '1' in each row.  another new result variable will contain count of some specific value in some specific columns

My data frame is like this

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 
0   1  2  1 
2   3  1  1
```

output I want is like

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 newvar1_count_of_1 newvar1_count_of_1_ in_first_2_col
0   1  2  1       2                            1
2   3  1  1       2                            0
```

Answer (score 0):

You only should do:

```
df1['newvar1_count']=df1[df1.eq(1)].sum(axis=1)
df1['newvar1_count_of_1_ in_first_2_col']=df1[df1.eq(1)].loc[:,['v1','v2']].sum(axis=1)
```

Applicated in your code:

```
df1['newvar1_count'] = df1.eq(1).sum(axis=1)
df1['newvar1_count_of_1_ in_first_2_col']=df1[df1.eq(1)].loc[:,['v1','v2']].sum(axis=1)
df1
```

Output:

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  newvar1_count   newvar1_count_of_1_ in_first_2_col
  0 0   1   2   1   2.0             1.0
  1 2   3   1   1   2.0             0.0
```